# How to get value of selectOneListbox

Tags: jsf

I have the following select items to be loaded dynamically:-

```
    <f:selectItems value="#{clientBean.onlineList}" var="user" 
itemLabel="#{user.nick}" itemValue="#{user.id}" />
```

onlineList itself is a list of a bean:-
`List<OnlineList> onlineList=new ArrayList<OnlineList>();`

```
    public class OnlineList {

Integer id;
String nick;
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getNick() {
    return nick;
}
public void setNick(String nick) {
    this.nick = nick;
}
```

}

When user clicks on a row, how do I get the selected object (the bean)?

Comment: May I suggest to start with some basic JSF tutorials? They will most likely include answers to basic problems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets supposed that you have

```
<h:selectOneListbox value="#{clientBean.selectedObject}">
<f:selectItems value="#{clientBean.onlineList}" var="user" 
itemLabel="#{user.nick}" itemValue="#{user.id}" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

The value of your `selectOneListbox` is being set to selectedObject (object of type OnlineList in your clientBean)